# How to fix ERROR: line_locate_point: 2st arg isn't a point?

Tags: postgresql, function, postgis

I created a function in postgresql that should find the projection of a point onto a segment, and then find the distance from the projection to a certain point. I have two arrays: the first array is array with segments (LineString3D), the second array is array with points that I want to interpolate (Point3D). My code:

```
foreach i in array(first_array)
    loop
    foreach j in array(second_array)
        loop
        select ST_LineInterpolatePoint(ST_LineMerge(i::geometry), ST_LineLocatePoint(ST_LineMerge(i::geometry), j::geometry)) into interpolate_geom;
        select st_length(st_makeline(j::geometry, interpolate_geom::geometry)) into length_geom;
        end loop;
    end loop;
```

But postgres show me this massage: `ERROR:  line_locate_point: 2st arg isn't a point`.
If you know how to fix this error, please explain.

Comment: Looks like there is an element in `second_array` that isn't a point.

Comment: ST_LineLocatePoint doesn't take 3D point possibly.Try doing ST_Force2D on your point geom and then ST_LineLocatePoint